# Bash script to pass two arguments to get status of ssl

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, case

I have a bash script "domain-ssl-status.sh". I need a script with two arguments so that I could run the script in the following way:

./domain-ssl-status.sh cname.domain.com status|unobtained|obtained|error

domainName and status are my 2 arguments

domainName=$1 and status=$2

I have tried creating a status_map using a case statement, but no luck!! I have also seen other hints on here but mine never seems to work. My sql statement includes SELECT * FROM DomainSSL WHERE domainName='cname.domain.com' and I'm still stuck.

Comment: Let us see an example of your script structure.

Comment: Edit the post so you can format it. ;)

Comment: #!/bin/bash

domainName=$1
status=$2

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    status)
        mssql -f csv -c ~/applications/mssql/mssql.json -q "SELECT * FROM DomainSSL WHERE domainName='$1'"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid argument: $1"
        exit 1
    esac
    shift
done

echo "SELECT * FROM DomainSSL WHERE domainName='$1' '$2'"

Comment: It won't let me edit it the way I have it written. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to edit the original post, not the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough pass at a rewrite -

```
#!/bin/bash 
domainName=$1 
status=$2 
echo "Verifying domain"
case status in
$status) ping -c 1 $domainName || {
           echo "Cannot ping $domainName" >&2
           exit 1
         } ;;
*) echo "Invalid argument '$status'" >&2
   exit 1 ;;
esac

sql="SELECT * FROM DomainSSL WHERE domainName='$domainName'" 
mssql -f csv -c ~/applications/mssql/mssql.json -q "$sql" # mark here
rc=$?
if (( rc )) # nonzero
then echo "FAIL: rc $rc on [$sql]" >&2
else echo "SUCCESS: $sql" 
fi
```

---

You might also want to try saving the stdout and stderr for later parsing.
Rewriting from `# mark` above,

```
mssql -f csv -c ~/applications/mssql/mssql.json -q "$sql" >ok 2>oops
rc=$?
if (( rc )) # nonzero
then echo -e "FAIL: rc $rc on [$sql]:\n$(<oops)" >&2
     case "$(grep SQLSTATE oops)" in
     *ER_DUP_KEY*) : code to handle duplicate keys error ;;
     # any other errors you choose to handle . . .
     *) : code for bailing on errors you don't care to handle ;;
     esac
else echo "SUCCESS: $sql" 
fi
```

c.f. the mysql documentation [here](https://www.briandunning.com/error-codes/?source=MySQL)

This is just a general template. Hope it helps. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: When I run the script, it needs to check for sql status, I'm trying to obtain a number. ex.
1-obtain
2-unobtain
3-error
./domain-ssl-status.sh 'cname.domain.com' 'status|unobtained|obtained|error'

Comment: Here's what I'm needing and thank you for help!
1. I need a scripts that accept 2 params and dies if not 2.
2. Use a case statement to handle different actions of param 2.
domainSSLStatusId in the SQL takes a number not a string!  Create a map

Comment: Why so specific?

Comment: When I run my script with 2 params, I need to know the status of the ssl. It could be 1-obtained 2. unobtained 3. error. That way we know how to proceed with the ssl cert

Comment: Sorry, haven't worked with mysql much in the last decade. Don't recall how to interface with ssl certs. :(